# Can I use "several entire generations"?

Tags: phrases

There's the phrase "an entire generation", but how do I describe that something had effected many generations? can I use "several entire generations"?

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly understandable to me, a native English speaker. (USA)

I also found several hits for it on a simple google search:

["several entire generations"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22several+entire+generations%22)

Comment: Note that at the time I posted this, the first 2 listings in that Google link are for this question.

Comment: Personally, I think the "several" is redundant.  "The war affected entire generations of citizens" is sufficient.  After all, normally, there won't be more than a few generations alive at the same time.